# wix toolset: How can I run or not run PowerShell depending on the result of DirectorySearch

Tags: powershell, wix, windows-installer

I am creating a MSI package including Visual Studio Code exe file.
I wrote directory search to check whether the  windows PC has VS code or not. Then, if the PC does not have it, I would like to run PowerShell to install VSCode and install a couple of extensions.

Right now, I confirmed that Directory Search and PowerShell are working. However, I am having a hardtime figuring out creating a conditional statement based on Directory Search then, run PowerShell.

This is my code so far:
**DirectorySearch:**

```
<Property Id="VSCODEEXE">
  <DirectorySearch Id="ProgramFolderVScode64bi" Path="c:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin">
    <FileSearch Id="ProgramVScode64bit" Name="code.cmd" />
  </DirectorySearch>
  <DirectorySearch Id="ProgramFolderVScode32bit" Path="c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code\bin">
    <FileSearch Id="ProgramVScode32bit" Name="code.cmd" />
  </DirectorySearch>
  <DirectorySearch Id="LocalAppDataProgramFolderVScode" Path="[LocalAppDataFolder]\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin">
    <FileSearch Id="LocalAppDataProgramVScode" Name="code.cmd" />
  </DirectorySearch>
</Property>
```

**PowerShell:**

```
<powershell:File Id="InstallVSCode" File="[#InstallVSCode]" Arguments="-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -AdditionalExtensions &quot;[#VSCodeExtension]&quot;, ms-azuretools.vscode-docker, ms-vscode.azurecli" />
```

This is the conditional code of block I have now. It seems that `powershell:File` is not expected child element of `Feature`..... But I need `Feature` to set the `Level` to use Condition..... Is there any other way to achieve this??

```
  <Feature Id="VSCodeInstalledOrNot" Level="1">
    <powershell:File Id="InstallVSCode" File="[#InstallVSCode]" Arguments="-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -AdditionalExtensions &quot;[#VSCodeExtension]&quot;, ms-azuretools.vscode-docker, ms-vscode.azurecli" />
    <Condition Level="0">VSCODEEXE</Condition>
  </Feature>
```

Thank you very much,

Comment: The DirectorySearch's should be evaluated during the AppSearch action, and the feature condition should be evaluated during the CostFinalize action. Take a look at your verbose MSI log file and see if VSCODEEXE is getting set or not.

Answer (score 0):

A word of caution.  While this is not legal advice, a quick search of github issues indicates that Microsoft doesn't extend binary redistribution rights to VSCode.  You may be limited to using AppSearch and LaunchConditions to block installation of your MSI if VSCode isn't installed and give the user instructions on how to install it themselves.

Also generally it's better to use WiX Burn Bootstrappers to detect if an application is missing and install it  then it is to have a custom action inside your MSI.  This is especially true for MSI installs as a Windows Installer Mutex blocks one install from installing another.   VS Code doesn't seem to be an MSI though.